# Setting up old Windows (95-ME) compatible Samba share on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, samba, nfs

I'd like to create a Samba share that is accessible with historical Windows (everything before XP) versions (VMs) under an Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I've Googled on this but so far no luck.

Comment: Try to make another partition in windows and install ubuntu to that partition

Comment: And what would it solve? Whenever i want to share data with the VM restart it and boot into Ubuntu, mount the NFS share, then copy data to Windows' partition and reboot again? It's easier to shut down the VM and mount it's vhd to somewhere on the host and copy to it all the data i want.